what is the scope of a c++ mutex lock guard?
I'm trying to figure out the scope of mutexes and mutex lock_guard and no one has been able to explain it to me.  Consider the following c++ code:
void somefunction
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex1);
    variable1++;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex2);  //what if I took this mutex out?
    variable2++;

    /*
    long block of code
    */

    variable3++;
}

I'm trying to determine what the rule for what a mutex lock_guard protects.  For example, in the current code does mutex2 protect variable3?  What if we took out mutex2?  Does mutex1 then protect variable1 variable2 and variable3?  How do I know what the mutex protects?  Thank you

This code won't compile. It declares two variables with the same name in the same scope.

Doesn't the manual answer your question? When control leaves the scope in which the lock_guard object was created, the lock_guard is destructed and the mutex is released.

Anyway, you are asking a wrong question. A mutex doesn't by itself protect anything. For a mutex to be helpful in preventing concurrent access to a piece of shared data, all threads accessing that shared data must agree to only ever do it while holding the same mutex. (I'm simplifying a bit; more complex access patterns are possible, e.g. MRSW lock). So what matters is - who else performs access to those three variables, and what mutexes, if any, do they acquire before this access?

To give you some general insight and examples for locking in general, consider studying my article on my personal website here: https://gabrielstaples.com/cpp-mutexes-and-locks/

It's the same as the scope of any other C++ object.  There's nothing special about mutexes and lock_guards in this respect.

so could another thread write to variable3 while this function is running in a separate thread or would the mutexes prevent it?  If I took out mutex2 std lockguard could another thread write to variable2 and variable3 or would they be protected?

A lock_guard locks its mutex, and keeps it locked until the guard's destruction. Any other thread locking the same mutex yeilds immediately, until current thread unlocks it (destructs the guard). The meaning of locking any specific mutex totally depends on the algorithm logic; a common pattern is have every single thread to wait on a specific mutex for a specific shared object. If your code violates the program logic rules(set by yourself), the result is UB.

@Matt123 so could another thread write to variable3 while this function is running As has been said, the threads must agree which mutexes they lock, otherwise, the mutexes protect nothing. The mutex does not know what it protects. It is the agreement between the threads which mutexes they lock that protects the variables. Therefore, if the other thread locks mutex1, all variables are protected; if the other thread locks only mutex2, but not mutex1, then variable1 is not protected.

As Igor Tandetnik pointed out, please [edit] your question and change the distracting duplicated variable name of guard.  You could, for example, change the names to guard1 and guard2.

Ok I think I get it now.  IF thread 1 locks mutex 1, any other thread attempting to lock mutex 1 must wait until the first thread unlocks.  IF this isn't correct someone please let me know but thanks everyone for all your help!

The std::lock_guard does not guard the variables. The std::lock_guard guards the mutex by ensuring that lock() and unlock() are called exactly once.
It behaves like
void somefunction
{
    mutex1.lock();
    variable1++;

    mutex2.lock();  //what if I took this mutex out?
    variable2++;

    /*
    long block of code
    */

    variable3++;
    // I assume the long code block has no local variables whose destructors would modify the protected variables,
    // the destructors of local variables happen after the manual method calls.
    mutex2.unlock();  //what if I took this mutex out?
    mutex1.unlock();
}

The mutexes are responsible to guard (synchronize) the access to a shared resource (variables or a critical section or something else).
It is a general problem that it may not be obvious which data is protected by which mutex as the mutex and variables are not directly bound to each other. It depends on the use case, but in some cases std::atomic can be a better solution, here it is obvious which variables are protected by what (the atomic variables protect themselves).
Note: In this context I would assume that mutex1 belongs to variable1 and mutex2 belongs to variable2, variable3 is unclear
As for //what if I took this mutex out?
If something else accesses variable2 or variable3 while holding mutex2 but not mutex1, then there can be a data race.
If every other access to variable2 and variable3 also has mutex1 locked, then mutex2 would indeed be useless and can be removed.

Ok I think I get it now. IF thread 1 locks mutex 1, any other thread attempting to lock mutex 1 must wait until the first thread unlocks. IF this isn't correct someone please let me know but thanks everyone for all your help!

@Matt123 Yes, this is the behavior of mutexes. Only one thread can lock the mutex and enter the critical section. All other threads which try to lock will wait until the owning thread unlocks the mutex.

There's no need to speculate about the behavior when you can do an experiment and see for yourself how the scoping rules work.
I've modified your code slightly so that instead of declaring a couple of std::lock_guard objects, it declares a couple of LetsTryIt objects... these objects call printf() with a helpful message so we can see where the mutexes would get locked/unlocked in the real code.   I also put in some printf() calls at various points within main() to make the sequence of execution more apparent.
Here's the modified code:
#include <stdio.h>

class LetsTryIt
{
public:
   LetsTryIt(const char * desc) : _desc(desc)
   {
      printf("LetsTryIt ctor [%s] ... lock() would occur here\n", _desc);
   }

   ~LetsTryIt()
   {
      printf("LetsTryIt dtor [%s] ... unlock() would occur here\n", _desc);
   }

private:
   const char * _desc;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
   int variable1=0, variable2=0, variable3=0;

   printf("Step 1\n");

   LetsTryIt guard1("mutex1");
   variable1++;

   printf("Step 2\n");

   LetsTryIt guard2("mutex2");
   variable2++;

   printf("Step 3\n");
   /*
   long block of code
   */

   variable3++;

   printf("Step 4\n");

   return 0;
}

... and here is the output that I see when I run the test program:
$ ./a.out
Step 1
LetsTryIt ctor [mutex1] ... lock() would occur here
Step 2
LetsTryIt ctor [mutex2] ... lock() would occur here
Step 3
Step 4
LetsTryIt dtor [mutex2] ... unlock() would occur here
LetsTryIt dtor [mutex1] ... unlock() would occur here

Note that the idea of a mutex "protecting" a variable is a bit misleading -- a mutex has no idea about the existence of other variables at all; the only thing it is good for is guaranteeing that a call to its lock() method will not return until the calling thread has gained ownership of the mutex.  Any further guarantees beyond that are the responsibility of your code (and in particular, what variables all your code is careful never to access outside of a critical-section where it has the appropriate mutex already locked).
Because of that, it's hard to say how your variables are protected, since we don't know what other code might be accessing those variables and whether or not that other code locked the same mutexes first, or not.  But if we can assume that the only function that ever accesses those variables is somefunction(), then we can see that any thread that calls somefunction() will block in the first line of the function until it has obtained ownership of mutex1, and it will not unlock mutex1 until the function returns.  Therefore the entire function body is serialized by mutex1, so locking mutex2 is unnecessary/superfluous.

Hi Jeremy.  Thanks for helping me out.  I'm still unclear, if I go back to my code, could another thread write to variable3 while this function is running in a separate thread?  What if I took out the mutex2 line?  Could another thread write to variable2 and variable3 or is mutex1 protecting them?  Thank you so much.

@Matt123 the mutexes are completely unrelated to the variables, what other threads can do depends on which mutexes they try to lock, not which variables they try to manipulate

@Matt123 another thread could indeed write to those variables, and if it did so without locking the appropriate mutex first, then your program would have a race condition.
